# how to open default blackberry browser when click on loaded page through browserfield

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

how to open default blackberry browser when click on browserfield.
i am trying load a html page on browserfield when i click on opened browser page that time i want to open blackberry default browser.

```
BrowserField browser = new BrowserField();

    MyBrowserFieldListener listener = new MyBrowserFieldListener();
    browser.addListener(listener);

    MainScreen screen = new MainScreen();
    screen.add(browser);
    pushScreen(screen);

    browser.requestContent(url);
```

i use this code it works but it also load in browserfield i dont want to load on browserfied

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing. Do you want to use a BrowserField or not? Are you wanting to open the URL in the actual browser, or do you mean you want to initially load a page with the BrowserField and then have links clicked in that open up in the BB browser instead of the BrowserField?

Comment: i have an html that have a URL.
first i was load html in BrowserField when i click on loaded html than i get a URL.
i want to open this URL in blackberry native browser but i don't want to any change in my html means fetched URL should not load in browserField or stay as it is..

Comment: If you have any idea related this issue please help me.....
Thanks in Advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always easier to answer questions when they have some information on what you are trying to accomplish. Like jprofitt I'm confused about what you want to happen. However, it is a bit of a kluge but you could:

1. in MyBrowserFieldListener detect that a link has been clicked when documentLoaded is called;
2. get the URL from the BrowserField with getDocumentUrl();
3. Launch the default browser with that URL;
4. If you want the BrowserField to remain on the original page call requestContent() or back().

Comment: ---  can u please describe your fourth point bcoz i want to make little bit same i want to open new getDocumentUrl(); in my device default native browser and than want to restrict the same url to load on browserfield --- 

4. If you want the BrowserField to remain on the original page call requestContent() or back().

Comment: When the user clicks on a URL in the BrowserField, the field will load that URL. There are two ways to get it back to the original page: issue another call to requestContent() with the URL you want displayed there (this is probably the best choice as it will avoid redirection) or issue a call to back() which will cause the field to go to the previous URL in the history stack. A more complicated way would be to use the BrowserFieldConfig to set the BrowserFieldController and over ride handleNavigationRequest() but I don't have any experience with that.

Comment: thanks for your reply..
i want only the url when user click on link but here i want to restrict browser field to load link and that link i want to open in default native browser.
i use browserfield.back() method but it occurred problems some time or not work properly.
you have any idea how to pause or stop or restrict the browser field.

Comment: The BrowserFieldController seems to provide that, but the only way to set it is with the BrowserField(BrowserFieldConfig config) constructor. I haven't used this myself so I can't be any more helpful.

Comment: I use back method when load browserfield but it occurred problem sometime.
have you any other idea.....?